# Output of caesar shift reversed

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to implement a simple caesar shift using java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Caesar_shift {
public static String message;
public static String Shift_msg;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please type message: ");
    message = scanner.next();
    setShift_msg(message);
    System.out.println(Shift_msg);
}


public static String setShift_msg(String msg) {
    String valueOf;
    for (int i = 0, n = msg.length(); i < n; i++) {
        char c = msg.charAt(i);
        c = (char) (c + 1);
        valueOf = String.valueOf(c);
        Shift_msg = valueOf += Shift_msg;
    }
    return Shift_msg;
}
```

}

When I run my program,

`String message = "abc"`

I should get the output bcd. However, it returns "dcbnull".

How could I fix it, and also why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line `Shift_msg = valueOf += Shift_msg;` to `Shift_msg += valueOf;`
That explains why it was reversed. And to get rid of the `null` at the end, set `Shift_msg = "";` either at the beginning of the method or when at the string declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code corrected

You made a mistake with the misorder of concatenation.

It should have been `Shift_msg += valueOf` since you're going from beginning to end also with the original message.

The reason you have gotten `null` is because `Shift_msg` had no value to begin with, hence it should be an empty `String`.

```
public static String message;
public static String Shift_msg = "";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please type message: ");
    message = scanner.next();
    setShift_msg(message);
    System.out.println(Shift_msg);
}


public static String setShift_msg(String msg) {
    String valueOf;
    for (int i = 0, n = msg.length(); i < n; i++) {
        char c = msg.charAt(i);
        c = (char) (c + 1);
        valueOf = String.valueOf(c);
        Shift_msg += valueOf;
    }
    return Shift_msg;
}
```